# Como retornar o numero de elementos de uma propriedade dos documentos em uma coleção no MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

Olá, tenho uma coleção que tem os documentos com o formato abaixo:

```js
{
    "_id"   : ObjectId("..."),
    "checked": true,
    "styles": ["foo", "bar", "bin"]
}
```

Preciso somar o tamanho do array `styles` para todos os documentos que atendam um filtro, ex:

```js
db.test.find({ checked: { $exists : true } })/* aqui entraria o resto da query*/
```

Como deve ser a query para que eu possa gerar essa soma (no MongoDB). Se eu fosse fazer após retornar o resultado eu creio que teria uma perda de desempenho. Podemos dizer que seria algo como o código abaixo após o retorno:

```js
function getData(filter) { 
    /* retorna o resultado esperado*/ 
}

var soma = getData({checked:true})
    .map(x=>x["styles"].length)
    .reduce((a,b) => a+=b, 0)

/* soma representaria a soma do tamanho da propriedade styles */
```

Como fazer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Encontrei a solução abaixo:

```js
db.test.aggregate([
    {$match: {checked: true}},
    {$project: {size: {$size : "$styles"}}},
    {$group: {_id: null, total: {$sum: "$size"}}}
])
```

Answer (score 2):

Leandro, basta você adicionar o .count() no final da query.

```
db.test.find({ checked: { $exists : true } }).count()
```

Com isso ele vai somar todos os registros que atenderem o `checked: true` e vai fazer uma soma.

Continuação:

Consegui pegar o total de styles de cada objeto:

```
db.test.aggregate([
{
  $project: {
     totalStyles: { $cond: { if: { $isArray: "$styles" }, then: { $size: 
  "$styles" }, else: "NA"} }
  }, 
}
] )
```

Acho que isso já te ajuda. Teria que fazer uma condição para que todos tivessem `checked: true`, então somar o valor daquela variável que retorna o total de elementos.

Comment: mas não quero saber o número de documentos, quero a soma do tamanho do campo `styles` que existe em cada documento. No exemplo tenho 1 documento com 3 itens no campo, então o resultado será 3

Comment: Este campo é uma array? ou um objeto?

Comment: o campo styles é um array